# Does new version of Gatsby not work with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui, gatsby

I am running into this error

```
portfolio % npm install gatsby-theme-material-ui
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@5.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^5.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from gatsby-theme-material-ui@5.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-theme-material-ui
npm ERR!   gatsby-theme-material-ui@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Within my gatsby config I have the plugin but am noticing some weird styling for production. I assumed it was because it is missing something like gatsby-theme-material-ui for it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gatsby-theme-material-ui`](https://github.com/hupe1980/gatsby-theme-material-ui) is not an official plugin so it's only maintained and supported by his author and contributors so its actual state is quite deprecated. This means that you are relying on Gatsby's package version which is expecting a version `3` or `4` (`gatsby@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0"`) while you have the `5.3.3`.

If looking for other alternative plugins is not an option, you can bypass the dependency tree issue by running:

```
npm install gatsby-theme-material-ui --legacy-peer-deps
```

The `--legacy-peer-deps` will resolve the (old) legacy dependencies for the package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will be giving this one a try unless you have a recommendation. I first tried `gatsby-plugin-material-ui` but also got ! Found: gatsby@5.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^5.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-material-ui@4.1.0

Comment: `gatsby-plugin-material-ui` despite being more maintained and updated, stills relying on Gatsby 4 so it's the same scenario :/. You should install the package (one or another) using the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag to resolve the dependency tree then